# Are TIFF file headers and IFDs always 8 bit?

Tags: tiff

The question title says it all - are all TIFF file headers and IFDs 8bit? And the image data itself can be specified in a different bit order in the IFD, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, 8-bit and 16-bit in TIFF file refers to the image pixel data contained in the file itself. Headers and IFD are the same irregardless of what bit-depth the TIFF file is in.

The first 8 bytes forms the header for the TIFF file, and the IFD contains 12 bytes.

EDIT : You can find out more information about the structure of a TIFF file [here](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/tiff/).

Comment: right, so in 8bit, that means 8 bits per byte, right? and in emacs in hexl-mode, 11 would be one byte in 8 bit, but 11:11 would be one byte in 16 bit?

Comment: I'm not a Comp Sci student. :) I majored in journalism - try someone else.

Comment: It is very unusual to see a cpu where 8bits != byte. A byte is the smallest atomic unit of a CPU except for specialist CPU this is 8bits. Now if you are talking about comms, then 8bits is called a octet because bytes can be whatever is the atomic data size, which can be say 10bits.

Comment: @david: what do you mean by comms?